# Fetch Website Source Based On Client Computer Rather Than Server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using the following code to fetch html source website.

```
private string Extract_Source(string url)
{
    string output = "";
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest req =  (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse res = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader r =  new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    output = r.ReadToEnd();
    r.Close();
    res.Close();
    return output;
}
```

It can fetch source properly but the problem is it fetch website source based on server from where script executed (i mean where website hosted), but i want to fetch content based on client information (ip etc)

Is it possible in asp.net, if yes can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to exactly replicate a request from the client from the server, assuming the client is likely to be in a different location.

On the server side, you can get close by copying headers from the clients request (user agent etc.) to the request you're constructing, but this won't make the server side request appear to originate from the clients IP.

If you can use AJAX (i.e. the URL you are accessing is on the same domain) then you could have the client retrieve the HTML from the URL via AJAX and then post it from the client to the server with an AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for answering, request to be originating from server but i want to send client information e.g ip address so that source output returned based on client info rather than server info. Ajax will not work as its cross domain request.

Comment: I understand, but it's not possible to completely replicate a client request on the server. If it was, imagine the security implications i.e. any site could retrieve your Gmail inbox without you knowing.

Comment: Yes i know there is security implications in such requests. Such requests can be possible via java applets running on client machines.

Comment: It may be possible via a Java applet, but at that point you're creating a request on the client rather than server side using ASP.NET as was requested.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan Hi, I was wondering if you needed any other help with this, or if you were willing to accept my answer if not?

Comment: Thanks for your help, with my result, client based url parsing only possible if we use java applets as implemented in keepvid.com which can parse and generate youtube video url based on client computer as youtube video url only works if it generate on client system. so its not possible via ajax or server side scripting like asp.net.

Comment: For you help and taking time to my issue. i will accept your answer.